# normal! <C-]> Not working

Tags: key-bindings

```
function! JumpDef()
    normal! <C-]>
endfunction
if &filetype != "elixir"
    nnoremap <C-]> :call JumpDef()<CR>
endif
```

If the filetype is not elixir, pressing `<C-]>` does nothing. I would have expected the above to do exactly the same thing as if the above code was not there. Why does it not exist?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The notation you're using for `CTRL-]` doesn't work in that context. The command you're using will act as though you had typed the following five keystrokes in normal mode: <kbd><</kbd><kbd>C</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>]</kbd><kbd>></kbd>

In order to invoke the `CTRL-]` functionality, use the following instead:

```
:execute "normal! \<C-]>"
```

(See `:help :execute` and `:help string` for more details of how this works.)

As an aside, if the code you've pasted is in your `vimrc`, it won't have the effect you're aiming for, of creating a mapping that doesn't apply to the elixir filetype.

The code in your vimrc is run when Vim is starting up before the file is opened: at that time, `'filetype'` will never be set to `elixir`, and thus the mapping will always be created.

One simple way to fix this is to move the filetype check into the mapping:

```
function! JumpDef()
    if &filetype != "elixir"
        execute "normal! \<C-]>"
    endif
endfunction

nnoremap <C-]> :call JumpDef()<CR>
```